# Plotting Column against Boolean Column (Bar Chart)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boolean

Fairly new to python

Have a dataframe where I'm interested in what percentage of each company's documents have been submitted late.

There are 10 companies in the 'Companies' column (A,B,C,D, etc) and in the boolean column it's True/False depending on whether document was on-time or late. (There's about 5000 documents in total)

I want to create a bar chart with % as y-axis and each company has a stacked bar along x-axis.

Is this possible? I've tried the following code but it's just a regular bar as opposed to the bar chart:

```
ax = df13['Originator Company'].value_counts(normalize=True).plot(x='Name', kind='bar', stacked=True, title = 'Companies % On-Time', y='Percentage')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(xmax=1, symbol='%'))
ax.set_ylim([0,0.25])
positions = (True, False)

plt.savefig("LMCP Contractor.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

- generate sample data that matches your shape
- aggregate and shape (using `unstack()`)
- modify from number of True / False to percentage
- plot as a stacked graph

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Companies":np.repeat(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"),100), 
                   "ontime":np.random.randint(0,2, 1000)}).assign(ontime=lambda dfa: dfa.ontime.astype(bool))

# aggregated and shape data
df2 = df.groupby(["Companies","ontime"]).size().unstack(1)
# modify from totals to percentages and plot
df2.div(df2.sum(axis=1), axis=0).plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

[image]